# Map Entity Framework navigation properties to ViewModel objects

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, orm

I'm building a WPF MVVM Light app in Visual Studio 2015 using Entity Framework 6 with database-first model generation. I'm creating View Model classes for my models to use with my Views (user controls).

I've got the following three EF models; an `Employee` can have many `EmployeeStatu` and an `EmployeeStatu` has a corresponding `description` ('Leave of Absence', 'Archived', etc.) on the `ValidEmployeeStatu` model. So `employeeID` is FK on `EmployeeStatu` and `validEmployeeStatusID` is FK on `EmployeeStatu` (PK on `ValidEmployeeStatu`).

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.EmployeeStatus = new HashSet<EmployeeStatu>();
    }

    public int employeeID { get; set; }
    // More properties here...

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeStatu> EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
}

public partial class EmployeeStatu
{
    public int employeeStatusID { get; set; }
    public int employeeID { get; set; }
    public int validEmployeeStatusID { get; set; }
    // More properties here...

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual ValidEmployeeStatu ValidEmployeeStatu { get; set; }
}   

public partial class ValidEmployeeStatu
{
    public ValidEmployeeStatu()
    {
        this.EmployeeStatus = new HashSet<EmployeeStatu>();
    }

    public int validEmployeeStatusID { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    // More properties here...    

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeStatu> EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my View Model for Employee; the others follow the same pattern:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _employeeId;
    private string _securityId;
    private IEnumerable<EmployeeStatusViewModel> _employeeStatus;

    public EmployeeViewModel ()
    {
        this.EmployeeStatusVMs = new HashSet<EmployeeStatusViewModel>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmployeeStatusViewModel> EmployeeStatusVMs
    {
        get { return _employeeStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (_employeeStatus.Equals(value)) return;
            _employeeStatus = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // More properties here...
}
```

I'm using this LINQ query to fetch the data:

```
var query = (from e in Context.Employees
             .Include("EmployeeStatus.ValidEmployeeStatu")
             .Where(comparison)
             select new EmployeeViewModel
             {
                 employeeID = e.employeeID,
                 securityID = e.securityID,
                 firstName = e.firstName,
                 middleName = e.middleName,
                 lastName = e.lastName,
                 suffix = e.suffix,
                 job = e.job,
                 organizationalUnit = e.organizationalUnit,
                 costCenter = e.costCenter,
                 notes = e.notes,
                 createdDate = e.createdDate
             });
```

How do I map the navigation properties `EmployeeStatu` and `ValidEmployeeStatu` to my View Models? And how do you then return the values to your models from the View Model objects for `SaveChanges()`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the same as in first level of models. So inside yours creation of EmployeeViewModel do sth like:

```
employeeStatus = e.EmployeeStatus.Select(s=>new EmployeeStatusViewModel{...}.ToList()
```

When moving back to model the same kind of mapping but from ViewModel to Model.
Or you can checkout the automapper. Search for blogs.

Comment: Thanks, @jstadnicki. That makes perfect sense. Do you have a sample line similar to that for returning the data from VM to Model? Somehow I couldn't find good documentation on Automapper; many of the links had code for deprecated methods.

Comment: Search for automapper. You will see that there is no need for doing this by hand. Basically mappings 1-1 will be done automagically, both ways.

Comment: I'd love to use Automapper if I understood it, @jstadnicki :) The links I found had some but not complete beginner's guide. The "Getting Started" from the main site didn't do much help for a noob like me! I'd love to see what you wrote above in Automapper syntax.

Comment: Try this: its first I found, but it cover the basic steps you need to start with AM. About 5 minut of read: http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/